# Extracting text from 'p' that's in 'div'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What I'm trying to do is simple, go to https://www.reddit.com/new/, and extract only the title of the first 3 posts. I've tried extracting the title of only the first one before proceeding to the next 2, but I keep running into problems. Would appreciate any help I could get.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


quote_page = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/new/'
page = urllib.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(quote_page).text, 'html.parser')
title_box = soup.find('div', {'class':'top-matter'})

title = title_box.text.strip()
print(title)
```

Error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ad044/Desktop/sidebar stuff/123.py", line 13, in <module>
    title = title_box.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
[Finished in 1.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/ad044/Desktop/sidebar stuff/123.py"]
[dir: /home/ad044/Desktop/sidebar stuff]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Comment: Based on your `'Error: NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` seems like you're not getting anything from `title_box`.

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand why it can't read the text that's inside the div. :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page uses javascript so you need a method like selenium which allows rendering for your elements of interest. You can then index into list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/new/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
data = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".kCqBrs")))[:3]
for item in data:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.